# Example of WebSocket Usage in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, websocket

I've been trying for some time now, unsuccessfully, to connect to a local server via WebSockets in Objective-C (specifically, iPhone) code.  I have tried the following three libraries, all with no success:

http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient

https://github.com/zootreeves/iOS-WebSockets

and zimt.

With zimt, I was unable to even include the files in my project without encountering any errors.

I was wondering if someone could please post some sample code that just simply connects to a server and performs a successful handshake/login.  It would be great if I could be given working code to finally determine if the issue is the way the server is set up or not.

I greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket), we just released it. It is [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) compliant.  Has some example code too.